# Python programming max heapify?

Tags: python

In python language:
How to write a function that takes a heap structure (that violates the heap property) and returns None. It changes the array slot in the heap structure so that the heap property is satisfied.

Comment: Smells like homework. Badly-worded homework at that.

Comment: Yeah I can't figure out what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

The function `heapq.heapify` from the standard library does this.